# Colon in Jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recntly updated my jquery from 1.4 to 2.1 and an error started appeared.

In my code I have a part where I select the elements with by an id.

`jQuery("*[id^=name:]")`

That produces an error, however there were no errors before(1.4)

If I escape the colon than the error disappears. Have they added anything new in the latest version or is it just a bug in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can wrap the attribute value like a string literal

```
jQuery('*[id^="name:"]')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rRLm6/)

Comment: Wrapping in quotes is simpler than escaping and "more correct" too since that's how you'd do it in actual CSS.

Comment: To answer the question.. I think it is in [jQuery 1.5](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rRLm6/4/) where the change was made... in [jQuery 1.4](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rRLm6/5/) it is working

Comment: @Dharman It looks like there were a quite few changes in 1.5 related to [selectors](http://bugs.jquery.com/query?group=status&component=selector&milestone=1.5) may be one of the could have caused the value change also

Answer (score 2):

You can escape it by double backslashes. From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

```
jQuery("*[id^=name\\:]")
```

or wrap your value inside double quotes:

```
jQuery('*[id^="name:"]')
```

Comment: I know I can, I am more interested in why it has come up just now with new JQuery version?